# Distributions on Meteor package server

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to understand what the docs say about the meteor package server.

> In addition to Isopacks, the Package Server contains distributions,
>   which are sets of packages that have been tested together by a release
>   engineer and that are known to work well together. For example, when
>   you use Meteor 1.0, you're using the METEOR distribution at release
>   1.0.

(https://www.meteor.com/services/package-server)

and

> Other people can also publish their own distributions to the package
>   server as well. If developer alice published a distribution called
>   SPACE-ROCK, you could switch your project to it by typing something
>   like meteor update --release alice:SPACE-ROCK@1.2.

(https://www.meteor.com/projects)

I know I can browse packages thru `meteor search ...` or on atmosphere. But the distrubutions are not listed there.

Is there any way to search/list distributions published to the package server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`meteor search`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteorsearch) will show releases (I believe a 'distribution' is just a release), but from the documentation, I can't find any way to limit it to *only* show releases.  Here's my result, as an example:

```
> meteor search
.... // literally all of the packages
Matching releases:                            
CORDOVA-PREVIEW      An experimental release of meteor with Cordova support.
GITHUBBLE            Release for githubble.meteor.com.
METEOR               The Official Meteor Distribution
METEOR-CORE          An experimental release of meteor.
WINDOWS-PREVIEW      Preview of Meteor on Windows
diegosampaio:METEOR  meteor 1.0.0 compatible
ekate:METEOR-SHOW    Meteor Shows Things
ekate:REL-TEST       test
ekate:TEST           Packaging UX Wrangling
glasser:PUBLISHTEST  Test release for isopack-cache branch.
glasser:TPS-PREVIEW  Preview releases for tool performance and stability work.
glasser:UPDATE-TEST  The official Meteor distribution.
konecty:METEOR       meteor 1.0.0 compatible
lawshe:FULLPAGE      Meteor smart package for FullPage.js. Create full screen pages fast and simple.
```

Comment: You are right. I just didn't search in uppercase :s. thanks Carson